# Forming query in DB2 to fetch row based on the values in one column along with order of another column

Tags: sql, db2

I apologize if the title seems absurd and lack information I am trying to explain the situation through following example:

Consider the following table-

```
ID     Event     Time
---------------------
1      EventA     ta
1      EventB     tx
2      EventB     ty
1      EventC     tb
2      EventC     to
```

I wish to select the ID such that there is an EventC after(based on Time) any instance of EventB.

I could think of the following query:

```
 select ID from TabET where
    ((select TIME from TabET where Event = EventC order by TIME desc fetch first row only)
    >
     (select TIME from TabET where Event = EventB order by TIME desc fetch first row only))
```

I am looking for a better approach and alternative as the table in reality is a very big table and this query is just a subquery inside a big query to satisfy a condition.

### Edit

The ID is not unique. The problem is to identify the IDs for whcich there is an EventC after(based on TIME) an EventB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join:

```
select distinct t1.ID 
   from table t1
   join table t2 on 
      t1.ID = t2.ID and
      t1.Event = 'EventB' and
      t2.Event = 'EventC' and
      t2.Time > t1.Time
```

Another approach:

```
with latest_times as (
   select id, max(time) as time from table 
       where Event='EventC'
       group by id
)
select t1.ID from table t1
    join latest_times on 
        t1.id = latest_times.id and
        t1.Event = 'EventB' and
        latest_times.time > t1.time
```

Comment: thanks. But it would be really helpful if you could tell that performance wise a self join would be better or a nested query considering the table has more than 100 K rows

Comment: @nishantv, see the update for another option.  However, a query with subqueries, like the one you posted, will be very inefficient.  Even if the subquery only fetches the first row, all rows must be returned and sorted for it to figure out which one is first.  Join is usually the better option.  Ultimately, though, you have to use `explain`, or at least test it, to find out which will be faster.

Comment: thanks . Its a new approach and certainly added to my knowledge.However, I have edited the problem a little. Could you please help with it as well. Requirement is to group ID and within each such group there shouls exist an EventC after EventB.